# Using Apps Script to create Calendar Appointment Slots

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I am using Google Apps Script to create calendar events but want to also create Appointment Slots. Apps Scrip appears not yet to support Appointment Slots (or am I missing something?). If not, does anyone know if this is this likely to be added shortly?

Answer (score 4):

This is still not possible. I created an empty calendar, and called the event listing API [here](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#try-it). I got an empty calendar. Then, I added a single appointment slot, and called the same API. I got the same empty calendar. Then, to make sure I wasn't high on crack, I created a test event, and called the same API. I saw my test event.

Therefore, it is my conclusion that Google Calendar Appointment slots are still half-baked, and not acceptable for integration in third party applications without some MAJOR hackery / web scraping.

Here's a listing of my results with one/no appointment slots:

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#events",
 "etag": "\"p32k9df48mm1dk0g\"",
 "summary": "API Testing",
 "description": "Testing Calendar API",
 "updated": "2018-03-23T12:10:57.161Z",
 "timeZone": "Europe/Moscow",
 "defaultReminders": [],
 "nextSyncToken": "CKiWvIi1gtoCEKiWvIi1gtoCGAY=",
 "items": []
}
```

and here are the results of one event:

```
{
 "kind": "calendar#events",
 "etag": "\"p33kdnpkimq1dk0g\"",
 "summary": "API Testing",
 "description": "Testing Calendar API",
 "updated": "2018-03-23T12:15:47.265Z",
 "timeZone": "Europe/Moscow",
 "defaultReminders": [],
 "nextSyncToken": "COjb5pK2gtoCEOjb5pK2gtoCGAY=",
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "calendar#event",
   "etag": "\"3043614692092000\"",
   "id": "5q94fuj2ufmgq29tmg4fibn8sr",
   "status": "confirmed",
   "htmlLink": "https://www.google.com/calendar/event?eid=NXE5NGZ1ajJ1Zm1ncTI5dG1nNGZpYm44c3Igbm92ZW50dW0udXNfZGpvdmRrdTdjNzNzbDFjZjl2ajFtaHQyYzBAZw",
   "created": "2018-03-23T12:15:46.000Z",
   "updated": "2018-03-23T12:15:46.046Z",
   "summary": "Appointment",
   "creator": {
    "email": "brian@pleasenospam.com"
   },
   "organizer": {
    "email": "noventum.us_djovdku7c73sl1cf9vj1mht2c0@group.calendar.google.com",
    "displayName": "API Testing",
    "self": true
   },
   "start": {
    "dateTime": "2018-03-23T16:30:00+03:00"
   },
   "end": {
    "dateTime": "2018-03-23T17:30:00+03:00"
   },
   "iCalUID": "5q94fuj2ufmgq29tmg4fibn8sr@google.com",
   "sequence": 0,
   "reminders": {
    "useDefault": true
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

This is how I recommend testing this functionality every six months or so if you're planning on integrating with this.

This is unfortunate. My customer has a web form on his website for scheduling events. He wanted me to integrate with his Google calendar, which would have been super cool for appointment scheduling. Unfortunately, this is not possible in the way we envisioned (get listing of appointment slots on his website, show those as available times, and then book them when a user selects one / submits the form.)

What I will propose instead is assuming what the appointment slots are, hardcoded, from the application. This has obvious drawbacks, and is not as cool for managing appointment slots. He could also have a "special" event that I scan for, and then use those as appointment slots (i.e. hack appointment slots into the API by a mutually respected magical word.)

With all the resources of Google, wouldn't this be cool to implement...? You know you want to.

Comment: FYI, exposing Appointment Slots to the Google Calendar API has been an open Feature Request since 2011: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36757162

Comment: @derekantrican thanks. I came up with a work-around by which we follow a naming convention for empty calendar "slots" (really events) and then rename them following another naming convention for full "slots." This is ghetto and circumvents the entire purpose of slots. We started down this path, my client ran out of money, so it doesn't much matter for me. It would be nice if Google removed these, or implemented them properly, but did not leave a half-baked piece of crap in place to waste my time.

Answer (score 2):

It does not support them and it is unlikely to do so in the near future, although in the long term we will probably add support for newer Calendar features eventually.

Comment: Any movement on this? A client of mine wants to expose appointment slots on his website, and have from submission book his appointments. The documentation doesn't give anything for "kind": "calendar#event". I am debating about trying this, and seeing if I get anything other than calendar events. Your example caller looks awesome. I'll try that!

Comment: I am interested in learning the progress as well. Isn't Google Calendar API capable to support Calendly like functionality?

Comment: It hasn't been implemented yet! Feb, 2023