# Create google calendar appointment slots via API

Tags: python, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api, google-apps

Google calendar has this feature called [Appointment slots](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/190998?hl=en)

But I can't find any API endpoints to create appointment slots.
Does the google api support them?
The documentation doesn't seem to mention it as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Apps Script to create Calendar Appointment Slots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724958/using-apps-script-to-create-calendar-appointment-slots)

Answer (score 0):

Reading Google's blog entitled ["Winter Cleaning"](https://googleblog.blogspot.ca/2012/12/winter-cleaning.html), Appointment slots has been discontinued last *January 4, 2013*.

> "You’ll be unable to create new reservable times on your Calendar
>   through Appointment slots*, but existing Appointment slots will
>   continue working for one year".

However, Google added an update to that article on *January 17, 2013*.

> "***Update*** January 17, 2013: We'll continue to support appointment slots in Calendar 
>   for all Google Apps for Business, Education and Government customers."

It remains a feature for those users, but there is currently no documented support for Appointment Slots in the API.

Comment: This is so super lame.