# Google calendar API and appointment slots?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to pull historical data from a calendar to see how many appointment slots were actually filled and how many were left blank. I've scoured the Calendar API, but don't see a good way to do this. any help?

Many of the answers I see around on google calendar appointments are several years old and outdated. I'd appreciate any up-to-date answers.

Comment: Have you tried reading Events? The Calendar API provides different flavors of event resources, more information can be found in About [events](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events).

Comment: as far as I can tell the API is completely dumb to the existence of appointment slots...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Apps Script to create Calendar Appointment Slots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724958/using-apps-script-to-create-calendar-appointment-slots)

Comment: FYI, exposing Appointment Slots to the Google Calendar API has been an open Feature Request since 2011: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36757162