# Google Calendar API, Appointment Slots, "This event was created from an appointment slot"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

What Google Calendar API can I call (from Apps Script) to determine if an event was created from an 'appointment slot'?

Google calendar knows this because when a calendar event is clicked, the detail 
card shows this text: "This event was created from an appointment slot".

Comment: As far as I know, apps script is not supporting the Appointment Slot as of the moment, this question was also asked year ago in [Stack Overflow site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724958/using-apps-script-to-create-calendar-appointment-slots). Also if you check the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/), you cannot find anything about Appointment Slot.

Comment: (1) I have checked the previous questions.  The distinction here is that I don't want to create appointment slots, I just want to be able to tell which of my calendar events are 'appointments' and which are 'events'.  (2) It's not in the API documentation, but I know it is possible because Google Calendar itself shows the appointment slot (see text from my original post).  (3) The greater question, perhaps, is what else I can do to distinguish 'events' from 'appointments'?

Comment: I was seriously disappointed by the appointment, and event, API for Google Calendar the last time I looked like a month ago. We abandoned it for our calendar needs because of problems similar to yours.